# Как сделать ввод строкой и потом разделить на числа?

Tags: python

Не принятое решение - `

```
a, b, c = int(input("Введите значение ")), int(input("Введите значение ")), int(input("Введите значение "))
assert -1000 < a < 1000, "Неверное значение a"
assert -1000 < b < 1000, "Неверное значение b"
assert -1000 < c < 1000, "Неверное значение c"
if (a > b):
    if (c > a): print (a)
    elif (c > b): print (c)
    else: print(b)
elif (c > b):print (b)
else:
    if (a> c):print(a)
    else:print (c)`
```

Препод запросил чтобы ввод оформлялся как строка, а потом делился на 3 числа. Cписок запрещен, split тоже.

Cмысл задания - "В единственной строке записаны три целых числа  a, b, c (−1000≤a,b,c≤1000), числа разделены одиночными пробелами. Выведите число, которое будет стоять между двумя другими после упорядочивания"

Comment: Срезы допустимы?

Comment: код должен быть прямо в вопросе

Comment: @Acinit раз не запрещено, то разрешено :) срезы, кортежи, словари, генераторы

Answer (score 1):

Я не могу открыть ваш код по ссылке, но предположу, что делитель между числами это пробел:

```
s = input()

# Инициализируем переменные a, b, c значением None
a = b = c = None

current_variable = ''  # Инициализируем текущую переменную как пустую строку
variable_index = 1

for char in s:
    if char != ' ':
        current_variable += char  # Добавляем символ к текущей переменной
    else:
        if current_variable:
            if variable_index == 1:
                a = int(current_variable)
            elif variable_index == 2:
                b = int(current_variable)    
            variable_index += 1
            current_variable = ''  # Сбрасываем текущую переменную

if current_variable:
    if variable_index == 3:
        c = int(current_variable)

# Теперь у вас есть переменные a, b и c с соответствующими значениями
print(a, b, c)
```

После того как получили переменные, внедрите ваше решение используя данные переменные

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения с функцией-генератором, которая извлекает числа из строки.
Ошибки ввода не обрабатываются для простоты.

```
def get_nums(txt):
    start = 0
    for i, ch in enumerate(txt):
        if ch == ' ' or i == len(txt) - 1:
            yield int(txt[start:i + 1])
            start = i + 1

a, b, c = get_nums(input('Введите 3 целых числа через пробел: '))
if a > c:
    a, c = c, a
if b > c:
    c, b = b, c
if a > b:
    b, a = a, b
print(f'Число, которое будет стоять между двумя другими после упорядочивания: {b}')
```

```
Введите 3 целых числа через пробел: -100 15 8
Число, которое будет стоять между двумя другими после упорядочивания: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ints(s):
    """ генератор, который выдаёт из строки целые числа """
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        while i < len(s) and s[i].isspace():
            i += 1
        j = i
        while i < len(s) and not s[i].isspace():
            i += 1
        yield int(s[j:i])


# вводим три числа
a, b, c = ints(input())

# сортируем пузырьком
a, b = min(a, b), max(a, b)
b, c = min(b, c), max(b, c)
a, b = min(a, b), max(a, b)

# печатаем среднее число
print(b)
```